# Can't find error

Tags: javascript

I can't find out why isn't this working, console doesn't say that there's an error, but when it's supposed to bring up the "prompt" 2-nd time it doesn't work.
Here's the code:

```
const Fanta = 250,Sprite = 250,Cola = 250,Dirol = 450,Snickers = 300,Lays = 800;
var a = prompt("1:Fanta = 250, 2:Sprite = 250, 3:Coca Cola = 250, 4:Dirol = 450, 5:Snickers = 300, 6:Lays = 800");
function math()
{
if(a == 1)
{
alert("You chose Fanta");
var money = prompt("Put money in");
alert("You put in " + money)
if(money >= 250)
{
    alert("You just purchased Fanta! Take back" + money - Fanta);
}
}
}
```

Comment: What second prompt? You never call the math function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some of the code wrapped in a function `math()` that is not being invoked. One solution is to just unwrap it (remove function):

```
const Fanta = 250,
  Sprite = 250,
  Cola = 250,
  Dirol = 450,
  Snickers = 300,
  Lays = 800;
var a = prompt("1:Fanta = 250, 2:Sprite = 250, 3:Coca Cola = 250, 4:Dirol = 450, 5:Snickers = 300, 6:Lays = 800");


  if (a == 1) {
    alert("You chose Fanta");
    var money = prompt("Put money in");
    alert("You put in " + money)
    if (money >= 250) {
      alert("You just purchased Fanta! Take back" + money - Fanta);
    }
  }
```

Another solution is to call function `math()`:

```
var a = prompt(...);
math();
```

You should call it after you assign to `a`. Of course then your function would use `a` as an, essentially, global variable - which is considered a bad practice - so you might want to refactor your code a bit to pass it to `math()` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, now i feel dumb

Comment: Happens to all of us. Who never wasted few hours looking for an obvious, trivial solution, is not a true programmer (TM) ;)

Comment: 100% True also OP don't forget to mark his answer as correct!

Comment: Oh yeah, it's a good practice to accept answers that solve an issue. Just saying because you're a new member @RichardNalbandyan. We also have this nice tour, in case you're not familiar with the site: http://stackoverflow.com/tour. Welcome! :)